# How to add minus sign in front of a string? (In C)

Tags: c, string, formatting

My string length is constant but actual data length will vary as like below,

```
"           1,54" // will be displayed as "- 1,54"
"123456789012,12" // will be dsiplayed as "- 123456789012,12"
```

Comment: @Javed would be the stupidest homework ever

Comment: @Thi If it is, please tag your question as so. We still are going to help you.

Comment: @Thi Also, it's very important that you review your other questions and ACCEPT some answers.

Comment: ["the homework tag, like other so-called 'meta' tags, is now discouraged."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10812)

Comment: @Will: no it isn't.  See Jeff's comment here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60422/is-homework-an-exception

Comment: @Jeremy in which he says he is torn on it.  Meta tags are discouraged, homework is a meta tag, so meta tag is discouraged.  There certainly doesn't need to be any discussion about whether this question is homework or not.  The fact is that it doesn't matter. Judge the question on its merits.

Comment: @Will: +1 for "judge the question on its merits"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've implemented below function to carry out my requirement. Converting input string into a number is won't work for me since my string has two part ("           123,54") with comma separated.

```
static char *
fmtsign(char * buffer)
{
     char               tmpbuf[20];
     char               number[20];

     int i, len, space = 0;

     memset(tmpbuf, 0x00, sizeof tmpbuf);
     memset(number, 0x00, sizeof number);

     len = (int)strlen(buffer);

     for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
     {
          if (buffer[i] == ' ')
          {
              space++;
          }
          else
              break;
     }

     strncpy(number, &buffer[space], len - space);

     sprintf(tmpbuf, "- %s", number);

     memset(buffer, 0x00, sizeof buffer);

     strcpy(buffer, tmpbuf);

     return (buffer);
}
```

Outputs:

```
- 1234567,89
    - 123,45
      - 0,00
```

Answer (score 5):

Wouldn't it be easiest to just put a '-' in the format string when you display the data?

```
printf("-%f", 1.54);
```

Comment: That was the first thought, but I didn't believe someone would upvote it.

Comment: @karlphillip: I didn't expect any up-votes either. Then again, I'm often surprised -- sometimes (what I thought was) a good answer that took a lot of work gets completely ignored. Other times, an obvious one-liner like this does get up-votes. C'est la vie...

Comment: bad solution: printf will not print a ',', with default-locale it print only a '.'

Comment: @Jerry - I have to remove spaces in fron of number and put a minus sign so just adding "-" "%f" won't work for my requirement

Comment: @Thi: actually, it will -- you just have to convert your input string to a number first: `scanf("%lf", &number);`. Alternative, you can leave it as a string, but strip off the leading spaces: `scanf("%s", buf)` (and use `%s` to print the result, of course).

Comment: @user411313: That, unfortunately, is all too true -- a minor detail I tend to forget since I usually use C++ (which provides, IMO, my better locale support).

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using **sprintf()** in this case.

I **updated** the code so it discards all whitespaces in the beginning but 1. That way you will have the **-** sign followed by a whitespace, and then the number. I left a few comments in the code along with some commented *printf()* to help you debug the code if you want.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char* num = "   1,54";

    int c = 0;
    if (strlen(num) > 0)
    {
        c = num[0]; // Safely storing the first character. Is it a whitespace?
    }
    else
    {
        printf("String is empty!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    int wspace_count = 0;  // number of whitespaces detected
    while (c == 32) // ASCII 32 = whitespace
    {
        c = num[wspace_count];
        if (c == 32)
            wspace_count++;
    }

    //printf("whitespaces detected: %d\n", wspace_count);
    //printf("total chars in num: %d\n", strlen(num));

    int chars_to_copy = strlen(num) - wspace_count+1; // +1 becouse you want to leave 1 whitespace there, right?
    //printf("chars_to_copy: %d\n", chars_to_copy);

    int tmp_size = chars_to_copy + 1; // another +1 becouse you need to append '\0' at the end
    char* tmp = malloc(tmp_size);
    int pos = wspace_count - 1;
    strncpy(tmp, &num[pos], chars_to_copy);
    tmp[strlen(tmp)] = '\0';    // add '\0' at the end

    //printf("tmp = \"%s\" \n", tmp);

    char* result = (char*) malloc(strlen(tmp) + 3); // 1 byte for the - sign, 1 for the  space after it, 1 for the '\0' at the end
    sprintf(result, "- %s", tmp);

    printf("%s\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

**Outputs:**

```
- 1,54
```

Comment: I have to admit that's better than mine. +1.

Comment: Btw, a minor comment, I think that since you want to add a small whitespace you should do `strlen(num) + 3` because AFAIK `strlen()` does not include `\0` in its calculations

Comment: will crash because you add 2 chars "- " and have only space for one.

Comment: @karlphillip - my source string may have space(s) in front of number. I need to put "-" sign before number.

Comment: Updated code according to suggestions. @Thi I might update the code to adress this NEW constraint, but it wasn't on the original question.

Comment: @Thi Updated the code to fit your demands. Don't forget to vote up or mark as ACCEPTED in case it solved the problem you asked.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like that:

Assuming `str1` is the old string

```
int strLen1 = strlen(str1);
char * newStr = malloc(sizeof(char) *(strLen1+ 2));
*newStr = '-';
++newStr;
strcpy(newStr , str1);
```

You could infact avoid `strlen()` all together and do

```
char * newStr = malloc(sizeof(str1)+1);
*newStr = '-';
++newStr;
strcpy(newStr , str1);
```

But keep in mind that what `sizeof(str1)` will return depends on how you defined `str1`.

Don't forget to `free()`

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you don't want the spaces to be printed out, so:

```
char str[LEN] = "          1,54";
char *nid = str;
while (*nid == ' ') {
    *nid = '-';
    nid++;
}
printf("%s", --nid);
```

Answer (score 0):

im guessing thi is french and ,= decimal if so then doing bitwise manipulation and calculation the two's complement should work.

in pseudocode:

```
temp = 2700;
newtemp = ~temp;
newtemp = newtemp + 1;      //Two's compliment
```